# How do I rename the initial programmatic ViewController class for my iOS app without involving storyboards

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been looking for a while and cannot find an answer to this question that does not involve storyboards.

It's quite simple. When you build a new iOS app in Xcode you are given the ViewController.swift file that contains the initial ViewController() class for the app. This view controller is the main view for the app.

If I rename the class to say ViewControllerTest(), when I build and run the app now only loads a blank screen since it cannot find the ViewController class as I renamed it.

How do I set the project in Xcode to use the new ViewControllerTest() class as the initial view controller?

Thanks

Comment: If you're not using a storyboard, how does `ViewController` get created before you rename it?

Comment: Well I found one solution but that involves using the main storyboard, simply selecting the storyboard and changing it's class to the new one ViewControllerTest works, but that seems so bass akwards an implementation...

Comment: You need to edit the configuration to NOT use Storyboards. See this article for a walkthrough example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6004856-building-an-app-with-only-code-using-auto-layout

Comment: great article, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disregard using the storyboard entirely, which I prefer because then all code is in one place, you need to add the following in your `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` depending on what version Xcode you are creating your project with.

**Xcode 10 and earlier**

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // Or whatever you want to name your view controller class
        window.rootViewController = ViewController() 
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window // retain instance
        return true
    }

}
```

for Xcode 10 and earlier you should also change the value of the `UIMainStoryboardFile` property to an empty string in your Info.plist.

**Xcode 11 and later**

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        // Or whatever you want to name your view controller class
        window.rootViewController = ViewController() 
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window // retain instance
    }

}
```

for Xcode 11 projects and newer, you should populate the `Application Scene Manifest` property as shown here:

[image]

Comment: For a new app you’d need the scene delegate, not the app delegate.

Comment: I included both implementations, as the Xcode 10 implementation is not obsolete, and thus still valid.

Comment: Yup that was all I was suggesting. “I have been developing like this since before Swift even came out.” Me too, and I recommend it too, for which I have been much criticized. Many of my published apps have no storyboard. That’s not the point. The point is just a matter of fact: in a new project created in Xcode 11 _merely_ adding the app delegate code no longer works.